# Is $(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T\mapsto(x_1\cdot x_2,x_3)^T$ a linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Is $f:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3,(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T\mapsto(x_1\cdot x_2,x_3)^T$ a linear map ($K=\mathbb{R}$)?

---

I say no, since

\begin{align*}
f([x_1,x_2,x_3]^T+[a_1,a_2,a_3]^T)&=\left[
\begin{array}\\
&(x_1+a_1)(x_2+a_2)\\
&x_3+a_3
\end{array}\right]\\
&=\left[
\begin{array}\\
&x_1x_2+a_1x_2+a_2x_1+a_1a_2\\
&x_3+a_3
\end{array}\right]\\
&=(x_1x_2+a_1x_2,x_3)^T+(a_2x_1+a_1a_2,a_3)^T\\
&\neq(x_1\cdot x_2,x_3)^T+(a_1\cdot a_2,a_3)^T.
\end{align*}

---

Have I understood this correctly?

Comment: Yes, but you have to give specific values for $x_s$'s and $a_i$'s to justify the in the last step.

Comment: is $f$ supposed to be a map $\mathbb{R}^{3} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Answer (score 2):

You're right that those expressions are not equal in general (and you want it to hold for all possible values). If you suspect it's not a linear map, try to find an easy counterexample and you can avoid the symbolic work with variables:
$$\color{blue}{f\left(\left[
\begin{array}\\
2 \\ 2 \\ 0 
\end{array}
\right]\right)}=\left[
\begin{array}\\
4 \\ 0 
\end{array}
\right] \color{red}{\ne} \left[
\begin{array}\\
2 \\ 0 
\end{array}
\right]  = \color{blue}{2\,f\left(\left[
\begin{array}\\
1 \\ 1 \\ 0 
\end{array}
\right]\right)}$$